# Can you make all links absolute in a request HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Hi i'm working on this project that uses requests to open links **without iframe** so i went this far but i'm stuck here. i want to make all links redirect to this project instead of the original site like when i search its https://example.com/site instead of https://example.com/link?link=example.com/site

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

app = Flask(__name__)
  

@app.route('/link/')
def link():
  
  r = session.get(request.args.get("link"))
  clist= (tuple(r.html.absolute_links))
  htmlc = str(r.text)
  for i in range(len(clist)):
    htmlc = htmlc.replace(clist[i],"/link?link="+clist[i])
  return htmlc


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)
```

(for i in range is what i tried)

first i tried to replace the html with replace and that didn't work
and then i tried to get help from ChatGPT and Google Bard but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.